# Is there anyway to make the bounding box around curved objects more precise?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

Firstly I am very new to Blender, and I'm trying to make a c-shaped wall for a tabletop rpg in Tabletop Simulator. I can make the model fine, but when I port the model into Tabletop Simulator because the bounding box encompassing the whole object, even the empty part inside, the other models I would like to place inside the empty space float on top. Is there any way to make the bounding box fit around inner part of the C-shaped wall?

Comment: see if you can find a convex hull in TableTop Simulator. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/rigid_body/properties.html

Comment: HI :). I asked Google about this saying "it's for a friend".  .. This is a link about importing a custom model into TTS. https://kb.tabletopsimulator.com/custom-content/custom-model/ and as 4nof suggested there are two options in the importer for this. Put a check against  the **No-Convex** option which i'm guessing is enough for such a simple model but for more complicated things it also has an option to import a separate collision model (simplified low poly version of the mesh) Scroll down the page to **Collider Tips** and **Non-Convex Tips** for more details. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you! That's so helpful. I didn't even know that was a thing, such a relief. Thank you so much! <3

Comment: You're welcome :)